# Eagerly fetching a lazy-loaded clob with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In a spring boot app using hibernate with an oracle database (and hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin to enable lazy-loading of lobs), I have a class `Category` with a lazy loaded collection of `Value`.

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Category.full",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "values", subgraph = "categoryValue"),
        subgraphs = {
            @NamedSubgraph(name = "categoryValue", attributeNodes = {
                    @NamedAttributeNode("children"), @NamedAttributeNode("detail")
            })
        })
public class Category {

...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "type")
    @OrderBy("sequence")
    private Set<Value> values = new HashSet<>();

...

}
```

Value has a lazy-loaded collection `children`, and a lazy-loaded clob `detail`.

```
@Entity
public class Value {

...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    @OrderBy("sequence")
    private Set<Value> children = new HashSet<>();

    @Lob
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "Detail")
    private String detail;

...

}
```

When using this entity graph to fetch a full category, `values` and `children` are joined in the initial query, but `detail` is not fetched, and an individual query is sent for each value, which is inefficient as most of these fields are empty.

Is there any way to fetch this field in bulk when fetching the full category while still having it lazy load by default?

Comment: Value has a self reference via children - do the values referenced by Category have their details fetched, or is it all values missing/lazy loading details when using the "Category.full" entity graph? Maybe try removing the Value.children mappings/relationship for now and trying the query to see if it makes a difference to your problem

Comment: All values in the category are contained in the `values` property of Category. Fetching `children` just loads the tree structure. Removing `children` from the entity graph adds as many queries to load that property as there are queries to load `detail`.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood what I suggested - I'm suggesting you try removing the 'children' OneToMany mapping outright from your Value class and see if that changes anything. You would need to unmap (mark it transient or just remove the property outright) and remove it from your EntitytGraph for testing, and see then if Hibernate returns the detail property in the main query fetching your Values. You might also show the SQL being used as that might help point out what is going wrong.

Comment: PS using OneToMany means there will be N rows returned. Do you really want/need to fetch that main 'value' detail lob N times if the 'children' are joined to your query? Lobs are one reason why batch queries are nice to have in other JPA providers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Criteria Query to achieve your requirement.

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;


CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Value> criteria = builder.createQuery(Value.class).distinct(true);
Root<Value> value = criteria.from(Value.class);
// Add below code to eagerly fetch detail to avoid multiple query
value.fetch("children", JoinType.INNER);
criteria.select(value);
```

You can also read more about criteria Query here

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-criteria-queries

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types

Comment: I am already able to fetch `children` eagerly, I want to fetch `detail` eagerly as well.